# Getting memory leak when combining Vala with C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, vala

The following Vala code combined with C is causing memory leaks and I can't wrap my head around it.

**Main.vala**

```
using GLib;

[CCode (cname = "c_function")]
public static extern void c_function (out Tree<int, Tree<int, string>> tree);

public static int main () {

    Tree<int, Tree<int, string>> tree;
    c_function (out tree);
    // If code were to end here and return 0, no memory leak happens, but
    // if we call c_function again, memory leak happens according to valgrind
    c_function (out tree); // Leak happens on this second call
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <glib.h>

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b);

void extern c_function (GTree **tree) {
    *tree = g_tree_new ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Memory leak in the next line when function is called a second time
        GTree * nestedTree = g_tree_new ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction); 
        g_tree_insert (nestedTree, i, "value 1");
        g_tree_insert (*tree, i, (gpointer) nestedTree);
    }
}

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a == b) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

I don't understand why if I call the C function only once no memory leak happens, but if I call it a second time, **line 10** of **main.c** which creates a Tree in a for loop causes a memory leak.

The code is compiled with

```
valac Main.vala main.c -g
```

And then run with

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./Main
```

I would like to know if it is possible to work around it. I tried emptying the tree in the Vala code before calling the C function for the second time. No success. Also tried destroying the tree passed as argument if it wasn't NULL on the second call of the C function. No success either. Still getting memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you've supplied I would look into using [`g_tree_new_full ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-new-full) instead of `g_tree_new ()` in your C code.

You are re-using `tree` as an out argument in the Vala code. So on the second call the first value assigned to `tree` should be freed. I'm hoping Vala generates a call to do that, but I've not written any sample code to check. You can compile your Vala code with the `--ccode` switch to `valac` to check the generated C.

So long as Vala is calling `g_tree_unref ()` then it is the set up of your C code that is not freeing the nested tree. You need a `GDestroyNotify` function for the nested tree to be passed to `g_tree_new_full ()`.

### Update

The error is in your C code. Your C code should be:

```
#include <glib.h>

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b);

void extern c_function (GTree **tree) {
    *tree = g_tree_new_full ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             g_tree_unref
                             );

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        GTree * nestedTree = g_tree_new ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction);
        g_tree_insert (nestedTree, i, "value 1");
        g_tree_insert (*tree, i, (gpointer) nestedTree);
    }
}

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a == b) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Note the use of `g_tree_unref` as the `GDestroyNotify` function when using `g_tree_new_full`.

The Valgrind leak summary now reports:

```
==22035== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22035==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22035==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22035==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
```

Before, with the code in your question, the leak summary was:

```
==21436== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21436==    definitely lost: 288 bytes in 6 blocks
==21436==    indirectly lost: 240 bytes in 6 blocks
==21436==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
```

Comment: The generated C code looks fine (Vala is calling `g_tree_unref ()` to be exact).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Setting a GDestroyNotify function on the nested tree still reports a memory leak in valgrind. I also noticed what might be a bug in the documentation of GLib. The text phrasing gives the impression that one must explicitely free the memory in the GDestroyNotify function, but if one attempts to do so, an invalid pointer error is thrown. When the function g_tree_destroy or g_tree_unref is called, the keys and values get destroyed at the end of the function call automatically.

Comment: I checked the gtree.c source code and regardless of a DestroyNotify function being provided, g_tree_destroy calls g_slice_free on the tree node structure. g_tree_unref on the other hand calls g_slice_free on the whole tree variable. The Vala code that calls g_tree_unref is not destroying the nested trees since it doesn't call g_tree_unref on the nested trees and therefore g_slice_free is not being called for those. Hence, the memory pointer references to the nested trees being lost when the root tree is destroyed.

Comment: I think that if one could get a strong reference to the keys and values of the root tree from the Vala code, one could somehow manage to free those references. Problem is, I don't know how to get a strong reference to those in the Vala code and manually destroy them. Iterating through the root tree gives me a weak reference to the keys and values. Not strong references for me to become the owner of those memory chunks.

Comment: Because you are using a nested Tree your GDestroyNotify function should be `g_tree_unref` in the C code call to `g_tree_new_full`. So when Vala calls the `g_tree_unref` for the parent Tree then GLib will call `g_tree_unref` for the nodes.

Comment: I tried it with g_tree_new_full on the nested trees, but the passed GDestroyNotify function is not being called on the nested trees when Vala calls g_tree_unref. I found the answer though. I'll post it now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. It was by no means trivial as it required looking at what Vala was doing and looking at the gtree.c source code to understand what was happening to the allocated memory of the trees.

Because Vala calls `g_tree_unref` on the root tree by default at the end of the program, the root tree is freed, but the memory chunks of the nested trees that were part of it are lost and not freed. One has to make Vala call `g_tree_unref` on those nested trees. A way to go about it is by owning the references to the nested trees. That can be done in the foreach `TraverseFunc` of the root tree in the following manner

**Main.vala**

```
using GLib;

[CCode (cname = "c_function")]
public static extern void c_function (out Tree<int, Tree<int, string>> tree);

public static int main () {
    Tree<int, Tree<int, string>> tree;
    c_function (out tree);
    // Iterate through the tree and get a strong reference to the values
    // to free them
    tree.@foreach ((TraverseFunc<int, Tree<int, string>>)valueDestroyThroughTraversing);
    c_function (out tree);
    tree.@foreach ((TraverseFunc<int, Tree<int, string>>)valueDestroyThroughTraversing);
    return 0;
}

public bool valueDestroyThroughTraversing (int treeKey, owned Tree<int, string> treeValue) {
    // Do something with the keys and values of the tree if desired
    // treeValue will go out of scope at the end of the method 
    // and Vala will free it
    return false;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b);

void extern c_function (GTree **tree) {
    *tree = g_tree_new ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        GTree * nestedTree = g_tree_new ((GCompareFunc)treeCompareFunction); 
        g_tree_insert (nestedTree, (gpointer) ((gintptr)i), "value 1");
        g_tree_insert (*tree, (gpointer) ((gintptr)i), nestedTree);
    }
}

gint treeCompareFunction (gint a, gint b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a == b) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how the C code should be written to free the Tree nodes. If you are ever trying to free memory like this in Vala then it is likely something else is wrong. It is usually a sign that the root problem should be fixed rather than trying to use Vala to work around it.

Comment: I've marked your updated answer as solution in recognition of it being more appropriate. But my solution still works for inefficient that it may be.